# Select inside a group

Tags: inkscape

I group two objects. Select both, go to object and Group.

To select an object inside a group I double click. But then, how I come back to the group? Making a search I found escape or ctrl ↵. I tried both and it does not seem to work. I click on the objects and are still selected individually. I suppose I am still inside the group but I do not see how can I be sure. How to know if I am inside a group?

If I close the file and open again and I click, it selects the objects, not the group.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click on the group to enter it. Double click outside the group to exit it.

You can tell if you are inside a group at the bottom of the document window in the statusbar.  If you can't see this, enable it in *View > Show/Hide* and make sure *Statusbar* is checked.

For example - #g848 is the name of the group here.  If you are in a layer (not in a group) it will show as Layer 1, etc.

[image]

[image]

Note: there's also a little drop down selector in the status bar, however it's a bit glitchy in Inkscape 1.0 on Windows, so I don't use it. Not sure what's going on there but it's probably a bug.

Another easy way to navigate between layers, groups and objects is to use the Objects panel (*Object > Objects*). It's particularly useful if you have multiple layers or nested groups (i.e. groups within groups).

For example

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+Click or using the node tool are additional options, that do not care about grouping at all.